# App runs fine in Debug mode but crashes in Release mode with sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, release-mode

I have a problem with an app developed using Xcode. It runs well in Debug but crashes in Release on a SQLite statement:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &init_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
NSAssert1(NO, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
if (sqlite3_step(init_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
... }
```

In Release mode it crashed at the line `sqlite3_step(init_statement) == SQLITE_ROW` with this error:

> Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

The following is the message I got before crashing:

> [Switching to process 7939 thread 0x1f03]

There is no problem found in Debug mode.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you setting `init_statement`?

Comment: Sounds like compiler optimizations might be exposing a previously hidden bug.  Does the static analyzer issue any warnings?

Comment: sqlite3_stmt *init_statement = nil;

Comment: After Analyze, 26 messages were issued in sqlite3.c, including some "Dead store"s and "Logic error"s with "Switch Branch" Badges.  sqlite3.c is with a "question mark" badge under a sub-project of my current project. I thought sqlite3.c is okay since it was not changed. Do those messages matter?

Comment: This is resolved by turning off the compiler's optimization of a sub-project. Not so sure about the reason.

Comment: Hello Huan, I am also stucked in same issue as above. Can you suggest me any solution in brief. Thanks.